# Selenium WebDriverWait does not work properly?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, freeze

I'm trying to take look at several pages on one web with Selenium - `PhantomJS()`.
The problem is that it started freezing and I can't figure out why. It is probably something with Timeout.

Here is the`__init__` method of a class.

```
self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=["--load-images=false"])
self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2)
```

And here is the method:

```
def click_next_page(self):
        log('click_next_page : '+self.driver.current_url) # THIS LINE RUNS
        rep = 0
        while 1:  
            try:
                self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.arr-rgt.active a'))) # IT MAY FREEZE HERE
                self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.arr-rgt.active a').click()# IT MAY FREEZE HERE

                print 'NEXT' # DOESNT PRINT ANY TEXT SO THIS LINE NOT EXECUTED
                log('NEXT PAGE')
                return True

            except Exception as e:
                log('click next page EXCEPTION') # DONT HAVE THIS TEXT IN MY LOG SO IT DOES NOT RAISES ANY EXCEPTION
                self.driver.save_screenshot('click_next_page_exception.png')
                self.driver.back()
                self.driver.forward()
                rep += 1
                log('REPEAT '+str(rep))
                if rep>4:
                    break
                sleep(4)

        return False
```

The problem is that it does not raises any exception or any message. 
The line `log('click_next_page : '+self.driver.current_url)` is working and then it freezes, I know it because I have `click_next_page : http://....` in my log as a last line.

The problem is definitely somewhere here:

```
self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.arr-rgt.active a')))
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.arr-rgt.active a').click()
```

But I can't realize where because it does not raise any Exception.

Could you give me an advice?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea about how Selenium works in PhantomJS. But, I am not seeing any issues within your code. To help you in knowing the exact problem, I would suggest you to debug it in smaller chunks and using one line at a time in console (not by running the python file).

So check with this :-

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=["--load-images=false"])
>>> wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
>>> code for clicking next page
>>> time.sleep(5)
>>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.arr-rgt.active a')
```

So, this should return you the selenium webdriver instance for the object you are searching using the css selector. If, the element itself is not found then it will throw error.

If the above code runs then re-run the above code with following modifications :-

```
 >>> from selenium import webdriver
 >>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=["--load-images=false"])
 >>> wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
 >>> code for clicking next page
 >>> wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.arr-rgt.active a')))
 >>> driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.arr-rgt.active a').click()
```

Here you will be able to check whether there is actually problem with wait_until(). If there is any error, you can point it out by running it one by one. Hope this helps...

Comment: pretty sure you mean time.sleep(5) and not time.slee(5)